# Processing Microsoft Office Outlook 2003/2007 email messages

Tags: c#, email, interop, office-interop, office-2007

> **Summary**

It's been while now that I receive emails on a specific work-related domain, and I'd like to build up a database based on the information that is provided within these emails messages.

These messages are work related items about some needs and requirements in the computer science industry in my corner of the world.

I would like to parse or analyze these emails in an automatic way so that I can get recurring information into a database and build a business intelligence-like database which would keep me informed about the most demanded field of specialization.

> **Technological environment**

**O/S:**     Microsoft Windows 7 Pro
**Office:** Microsoft Office 2007 Pro
**Yes,** I can use .NET 4.0! =)

*(I'll be pleased to provide further information as needed.)*

> **Questions**

1. How to access either PST files or the Outlook personal data files through the COM Interop assembly?
2. What are the objects to use to instantiate each of the emails found in the Outlook PST file or other?
3. What is the best way to go to parse an email message?

Thanks for any of you who can share her/his grain of salt in order to help me achieve my objective. That is very meaningful to me.

Comment: If you have access to the mail server, look at the powershell extensions for Exchange to see if what you want to do is easier there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use the Outlook 2007 COM object Model I suggest you start with this article: [How Do I ... in Outlook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208173%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Look specifically for "Folders and Stores", "Search an Filter", "Solution Storage".

Aside from this, the PST format is now documented here: [PST File Format SDK](http://pstsdk.codeplex.com/)
 but this is an unmaged C++ API, hard to use in .NET. There was a .NET port project initiated here: http://pstsdknet.codeplex.com/documentation but it seems quite dead (or not yet born)... so it's a difficult road to head for.

Comment: +1 I DO greatly appreciate your kind information. If you happen to cross any further details, please feel free to post it.

Comment: I'm currently working my way to write the application in C++/CLI and use the pstsdk. Thanks! =)