# CLR C++ VS C++ (pstsdk)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli, clr

Considering Simon Mourier's answer to this question:
[Processing Microsoft Office Outlook 2003/2007 email messages…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395223/processing-microsoft-office-outlook-2003-2007-email-messages)

I plan to use the [PST File Format SDK](http://pstsdk.codeplex.com/) which is written in C++.

I would take this opportunity to learn more about C++ and to renew with it, since it's been quite 15 years since the last time I used it. I have already downloaded and configured [Boost 1.45](http://file:///C:/Users/WILL/Downloads/Microsoft%20Office%20Outlook%20PST%20file%20SDK/boost_1_45_0/index.html) which is required to work with `pstsdk`.

Now, I'm currently writing a Windows Forms application using CLR C++ and plan to use the `pstsdk` to read from PST files.

**Does it matter in any way that I'm using both CLR C++ and pure C++ altogether?**

**Shall I consider using it a different way, or is this okay?**

Comment: Not sure what the point would be, C++/CLI is a different language, it is *not* C++.  But yeah, it will compile boost to IL.  Post back when you have a problem.

Comment: The fact is that I don't know any Windows Forms capable C++ except Win32's, which in fact is C. Besides, `pstsdk` is a native C++ library, so I thought I should do a C++ Windows Forms application, while using the `pstsdk` along, so I would have this headache of trying to make `pstsdk` library work in .NET, which I believe is quite not doable. Then, I came with this mix managed and unmanaged C++ solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a .NET (Windows Forms, or maybe even the newer WPF) user interface, the simplest approach is to build an object model in C++/CLI, implemented in terms of the native code but having a .NET interface.

Then write the UI in C# and call the C++/CLI object model (which differs from using the .NET base class library in only one way -- you have to add a reference to the C++/CLI assembly... but the C++/CLI compiler will create all the metadata that C# uses).

Comment: Please, forgive my ignorance, but how exactly should I do this? I mean, I created a Windows Forms specifying C++ as the language. I included the `pst.h` header file from the `pstsdk` library. I only use .NET because that is the only thing I know is adequate to build up Windows apps. I don't know what kind of project to create to be natively C++ while writing Windows GUI. I thought of .NET for this reason. Besides, I don'T mind not to use .NET, since this would push my learnings of C++ even further. Nonetheless, being able to make a C++/CLI accessed through a .NET C# GUI looks pretty interestin

Comment: In short, you create a ".NET Class Library (C++)" project and make sure it has some public `ref class`es.  Then you create a ".NET Windows Forms Application (C#)" and add a reference to the C++/CLI project.

Answer (score 1):

You can [mix managed and unmanaged code](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&expIds=17259,17311&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=mix+managed+unmanaged+code&cp=26&pf=p&sclient=psy&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=mix+managed+unmanaged+code&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=a20cfd04ba3c5cf9), but it will be a pain to marshal everything except the built-in types across the boundaries. It's much easier to stay with more powerful unmanaged C++. You could use CodeGear C++ Builder for example (or QT). The problem with CodeGear is compiler isn't that great, so you won't be able to compile everything from Boost, but you might not need that.

Comment: +1 for providing some links that show how to use managed and unmanaged code altogether.

Answer (score 1):

C++/CLI is *intended* to interop with unmanaged C++- that's pretty much it's entire purpose. However, I feel that it's probably easier to write in C# if you need .NET for, say, WPF, which is an excellent technology, and just use C++/CLI for interop.

Comment: And what if I then want to use `pstsdk` library along with `boost 1.45`, since it is required by `pstsdk`, in my C# GUI code? Does it suffice to add a reference or something? In fact, how to reference in C# a library like `pstsdk`, since it's a header-library that uses `boost`, and no DLL is produced whatsoever?

Comment: p/invoke is absolutely not a viable option for an API as template-heavy as boost.  C++ interop is the only way to use such things from .NET, and of course writing the whole app in C++ (no .NET) is also a possibility.