# C++: Getting the "error C2065: 'pst' : undeclared identifier" while using pstsdk?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unmanaged, managed-c++, pst

Following the suggestion of working with the **pstsdk** in this question:
[Processing Microsoft Office Outlook 2003/2007 email messages…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395223/processing-microsoft-office-outlook-2003-2007-email-messages)

And following the instructions here:
[PST File Format SDK - PST Layer Overview - Getting Started](http://pstsdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=pst&referringTitle=Documentation#Getting%20Started)

And also according to this video:
[In PST SDK Presentation, Terry Mahaffey, discusses the PST SDK file format SDK.](http://www.ditii.com/2010/11/04/webcast-binary-file-format-presentation/)
(Forward it to 28:32)

They all agree that I only have to include the PST header file after having properly added the include paths for both **Boost** and **pstsdk**, and to write the following code to start working with my pst file:

```
#include "pst.h"

pst myfile(L"myfile.pst");
```

Now, I'm using a mix of managed and unmanaged C++, hence I'm trying to put this code in my function like so:

```
private: 
    System::Void readPstFileButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        pst myfile(fileNameTextBox->Text);
    }
```

And everytime I compile, I get the c2065 error code that says the `pst` is undeclared.

**Any clue anyone?**

**EDIT #1**

After I have done as suggested by Hans Passant (which works), my code now looks like this:

```
private:
    System::Void readPstFileButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         pstsdk::pst myfile(marshal_as<std::wstring>(fileNameTextBox->Text));
    }
```

And I now get the following errors:

> error C3859: virtual memory range for PCH exceeded; please recompile with a command line option of '-Zm111' or greater
>
> error C1076: compiler limit : internal heap limit reached; use /Zm to specify a higher limit

I definitely didn't expect these to occur. How to solve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is declared in a namespace, as it should.  Fix:

```
 pstsdk::pst myfile(fileNameTextBox->Text);
```

Comment: Yes, and I figure out to have a type mismatch or something like so: `error C2664: 'pstsdk::pst::pst(const std::wstring &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::String ^' to 'const std::wstring &'`. I understand that is a fact of mixing managed and unmanaged C++, but I don't seem to be able to type cast in anyway.

Comment: Well, I warned you about this in your previous post, C++/CLI is not C++.  You need to convert the String^ to a wstring.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/bb384865%28en-us%29.aspx

Comment: Hehehe... Yes, you did! And I'm glad you did. Now, I wish to become as fluent in C++/CLI and C++ than in C#, or close to, at least. That is why I give myself this hard "homework", to learn the hard way. Working with a real problem, I will learn more effectively, in my opinion. Thanks for the link! =)

Comment: You have to start a new question.