# C++: Getting the c3859 error code while compiling in a mix of C++/CLI and C++

Tags: c++, c++-cli, marshalling, unmanaged

After I have done as suggested by Hans Passant in  [C++: Getting the "error C2065: 'pst' : undeclared identifier" while using pstsdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4594640) (which works), my code now looks like this:

```
private:
    System::Void readPstFileButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         pstsdk::pst myfile(marshal_as<std::wstring>(fileNameTextBox->Text));
    }
```

And I now get the following errors:

> error C3859: virtual memory range for PCH exceeded; please recompile with a command line option of '-Zm111' or greater
>
> error C1076: compiler limit : internal heap limit reached; use /Zm to specify a higher limit

I definitely didn't expect these to occur, and neither do I know how to solve them.

Comment: The errors tell you how to solve them.

Comment: This helps a lot! Thanks! Aside, though the error says it all, it seems that there's something missing to come on how to solve them, since I do not compile at command line,, but using VS2010.

Comment: Removed "Managed C++" tag -- managed C++ is dead -- if you're using C++/CLI, you are using what replaced "Managed C++".

Comment: Thanks Billy ONeal! I didn't know that, just learned something new!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

1. Right-click your C++ project in Solution Explorer; choose Properties.
2. In the Properties dialog, expand Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Command Line
3. In Additional Options, add `/Zm120`

Repeat this for Debug and Release and any other configurations you have.

For more information on what this command-line option does (and what changing it means), see [the /Zm documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdscwf1c(v=VS.100).aspx).

Comment: This compiles properly, plus I now understand what the `/Zm` option switch does, which helps me to learn more adequately. Thanks! =) (+1 and accepted answer)

Comment: Just a tip: you can select all projects and add the same property sheet to them in one step. The sheet will also be added to debug and release builds.

Comment: this simply does not work for hundreds of people.  We have already set to the max..  And it's completely random whether this error comes up on a rebuild all.