# Building OpenCV 2.4.5 with TBB - missing tbb_debug.lib

Tags: opencv, build, tbb, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to compile OpenCV 2.4.5 with MSVC2010 Express under win64

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'tbb_debug.lib'

All my paths are set correctly in cmake. It appears that in my TBB lib dir, I have tbb_debug.dll, but not tbb_debug.lib. I compiled tbb from source, however, there does not seem to be a tbb.lib in the prebuilt TBB packages either. Why is OpenCV asking for a .lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy the release lib to the debug folder - it's missing.

I thought it was fixed on 2.4.5 but it no longer uses tbb on Windows so no experience

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. I do not have tbb.lib nor tbb_debug.lib -- only dll's

Comment: Download the tbb package from intel, it should have a tbb.lib, it doesn't come with opencv

Comment: I do have tbb. It comes only with tbb.dll and tbb_debug.dll. No .lib

Comment: Redownload from [here](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/sites/default/files/software_releases/windows/tbb41_20130314oss_win.zip). In the lib folder, you can find the required files.

Comment: Thanks dilgenter. That worked. I had compiled tbb from source actually, and it did not build the .lib files. There must some configure option I'm not aware of to build the libs.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled building OpenCV with TBB for the past couple of days. I managed to compile it in the end; please find my CMake settings and other findings in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16480533/1792932).